# Joomla 2.5 Get User Data from External Script

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, external-script

I need to get the information of the user that's currently logged in to Joomla from a program outside of Joomla itself.  I upgraded from 1.5 to 2.5, and what I had before doesn't work anymore.

```
<?php

define( '_VALID_MOS', 1 );

include_once( 'globals.php' );
require_once( 'configuration.php' );
require_once( 'includes/joomla.php' );
$option="test";
$mainframe = new mosMainFrame( $database, $option, '.' );
$mainframe->initSession();

$my = $mainframe->getUser();
$joomla_name = $my->name;
$joomla_email = $my->email;
$joomla_password = $my->password;
```

After some research, I've come up with this:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'DS', '/' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'configuration.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'joomla'.DS.'factory.php' );

$my =& JFactory::getUser();
$joomla_name = $my->name;
$joomla_email = $my->email;
$joomla_password = $my->password;
$joomla_username = $my->username;
```

It doesn't produce any errors but seems to work. However, the user object is empty.  This script is in the same directory as the Joomla installation.  What may be the problem?  Thanks!

Sources:

http://www.cmsbloke.com/accessing-joomla-objects-from-an-external-script/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from 
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_access_session_variables_set_by_an_external_script

Solution: Replace `session_start();` in your external script with

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../..' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
```

Be sure to change `JPATH_BASE` to suit your directory structure.

Replace the `$_SESSION[ 'name' ] = "value";` in your external script with

```
$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('name', "value");
Now you can retrieve this session variable using:

$session =& JFactory::getSession();
echo $session->get('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I think people have had problems with this in Joomla 2.5 as things have changed. I haven't found a solution for the way you have requested but wrote this work around (excluding the password field though) that you may want to use.</strike>

define a connection to the database:

```
<?php
   $host="localhost";
   $username="DB_USERNAME";
   $password="DB_PASSWORD";
   $db_name="DB_NAME";
   mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db($db_name)or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Echo create a query and echo the results in a table:

```
<table style="background:#FFF; color:#000;">
<?php
$query = "SELECT username,name,email FROM j25_users "; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<tr><td>',$row["username"],'</td><td>',$row["name"],'</td><td>',$row["email"],'</td></tr>' ;
    }
?>
</table>
```

You will need to change j25_users to the correct prefix of your database tables.

Update: Much better to import the framework to get the user object.

Hope this comes in handy for you. Regards.

Comment: Okay, we're getting closer.  However, the code I had before got the information about the _currently logged-in user_.  How can I get that information here?  I believe Joomla has a custom session implementation because the data isn't in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Not too sure. I tried using a script and implementing the libraries but it kept saying "JFactory class not found". If you do get it working then please share cause I would also really like to know how to do this. Regards

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, I had two problems:

1. My script was on `www.example.com`, while I was logged in under `example.com`, so the different domain was throwing off the session data.
2. I also wasn't initialising the application, which apparently is necessary.

Here are the results:

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
define( 'DS', '/' );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

JFactory::getApplication('site')->initialise();

$user = JFactory::getUser();
$joomla_name = $user->name;
$joomla_email = $user->email;
$joomla_password = $user->password;
$joomla_username = $user->username;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip using Joomla! functions, you can query the Joomla! database. Join tables `js25_session` and `js25_users` with the user id. This way, you can get every currently logged-in user and all guests on the website (and possibly the number of online users).