# TCPDF class not found in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, tcpdf

I am using `TCPDF` to create pdf in `joomla`. I have include `tcpdf.php` using `require_once` and it is successfully included but when I am creating object of `TCPDF` class gives `fatel error: TCPDF class not found ;`

Thanks

Comment: How do you verify its successfully included?

Comment: Which file did you add `require_once` to?

Comment: i have place tcpdf folder in public_html and set require_once(JURI::root().'tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

Comment: You can't use `JURI::root()` in a custom PHP file unless you import the Joomla framework in the file too. This answer gives you the code to put at the top of your PHP file which will import the framework: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12665691/1362108

Comment: sir  require_once(JURI::root().'tcpdf/tcpdf.php'); this i have write in joomla view file so JURI is working correctly i have check by echo it gives me correct path

Comment: Which view file have you added it to? It might be possible that you have added it to a view file that isn't being used on that specific page. Try adding it to your template index.php file instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace this code:

```
require_once(JURI::root().'tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

with

```
require_once(JPATH_ROOT . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the tcpdf_include.php file and change the $tcpdf_include_dirs array values (line 30) as per your requirement or just directly include the tcpdf.php

I did something like this and it working...

```
require_once('tcpdf.php')
```

my tcpdf_include.php and tcpdf.php files are in same folder.

hope this will help.